# Extract coordinates from polyline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line

I have a shapefile with 64 lines with the metadata:

```
General:
Storage type of this layer: ESRI Shapefile
Source for this layer: C:/Users/toke.nielsen/Desktop/lines.shp
Geometry type of the features in this layer: Line
The number of features in this layer: 64
Editing capabilities of this layer: Add Features, Delete Features, Change Attribute Values, Add Attributes, Delete Attributes, Create Spatial Index, Fast Access to Features at ID, Change Geometries
Extents:
In layer spatial reference system units : xMin,yMin 563677.42,6223900.13 : xMax,yMax 568136.66,6227899.44
Layer Spatial Reference System:
+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

How do I export the coordinates from these lines to a .csv file? I have tried to write GEOMETRY=AS_XY in the layer options when creating the .csv and I have tried the vector->geometry tools->export/add geometry columns, but then I only get the length of each line.

Comment: I have figured it out. I used GEOMETRY=AS_WKT in the layer option when saving to csv.

Comment: The mmqgis plugin lets you easily extract the node coordinates of a line or polygon.

Comment: @Toke, it'd be great if you went ahead and created a full answer below showing all the steps and results (then 'accept' it if no-one answers with something better).